# conditional ant rule

Tags: android, ant

This is my custom_rules.xml which is called from 'build.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="custom_rules">
<xmlproperty file="AndroidManifest.xml" prefix="mymanifest" collapseAttributes="true"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="releases" />   
  <property name="version.name" value="${mymanifest.manifest.android:versionName}" />   
   <property name="version.code" value="${mymanifest.manifest.android:versionCode}" />   
   <property name="out.file" value="${ant.project.name}-${version.name}_${version.code}.apk" />   
<target name="-post-build">
    <echo>Output filename: ${out.file}</echo>
    <copy file="${out.final.file}" tofile="${build.dir}/${out.file}"/>
</target>
```

What I want to do is that the above should only be executed if ant was launched with
    ant release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually deal with it:

- make the "release" target set a property. Something like:

`<property name="isreleasing" value="true" />`

- add an if to the target to execute only is there is a release. With somehting like:

`<target name="-post-build" if="isreleasing">`

`...`